# Captcha php ... I dont know what is error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am new in php and i want to do capthca ... I wrote the code, validation etc , and as a result i get only small picture ... and nothing on it ... and my program dont tell me where is an error

This is my code in **captcha.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();`enter code here`


  // build the base captcha image 

$img = imagecreatetruecolor(80,30);

$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($img,150,150,150);
$red = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 0, 0);
$pink = imagecolorallocate($img, 200, 0, 150);

// build the base captcha image - END

// building randomString 
function randomString($length){
    $chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz023456789";
    srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
    $str = "";
    $i = 0;

        while($i <= $length){
            $num = rand() % 33;
            $tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1);
            $str = $str . $tmp;
            $i++;
        }
    return $str;
}

for($i=1;$i<=rand(1,5);$i++){
    $color = (rand(1,2) == 1) ? $pink : $red;
    imageline($img,rand(5,70),rand(5,20), rand(5,70)+5,rand(5,20)+5, $color);
}
// building randomString - END

// fill  image with a white rectangle
imagefill($img, 0, 0, $white);

$string = randomString(rand(7,10));
$_SESSION['string'] = $string;

imagettftext($img, 11, 0, 10, 20, $black, "calibri.ttf", $string);
// fill  image with a white rectangle - END

//  type of image
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($img);


?>
```

And this is my code in **contact.php**:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if(!empty($_POST['ime']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['poruka']) && !empty($_POST['code'])) {

        if($_POST['code'] == $_SESSION['rand_code']) {

            // send email
            $accept = "Poruka uspesno poslata.";

        } else {

            $error = "Pogresan kod.";
              }

    } else {

        $error = "Molimo Vas popunite sva polja.";    
    }
 }

?> 

<!DOCTYPE html >
<html >
<head>
<title>Kontaktirajte nas</title>

</head>

<body>

<?php if(!empty($error)) echo '<div class="error">'.$error.'</div>'; ?>
<?php if(!empty($accept)) echo '<div class="accept">'.$accept.'</div>'; ?>

<form  method="post">
    <p>Ime<input type="text" name="ime" /></p>
    <p>Email<input type="text" name="email" /></p>
    <p>Poruka<textarea name="poruka" rows=”25” cols=”40”></textarea></p>
        <img src="captcha.php"/>
    <p>Posalji<input type="text" name="code" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Posalji" class="button" /></p>
    <p>"IPO" MASARIKOVA br.5, BEOGRAD</p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what result do you expect? Do you have `error_reporting` turned on? Have you tried visiting captcha.php **without** the `header` changing-type to see if it is printing some error?

Comment: i didnt .. but i will try .. thank you ...

Comment: i expected  to get image where should write some mix of random letters and numbers ... but i get only image of broken picture ... if u know what i mean ...

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. I tested your code and i get a random string of characters with random lines crossing through it... i did have to find a `calibri.ttf` file and put it in the same directory as `captcha.php`. Also, had to change `$_SESSION['string']` in captcha.php to `$_SESSION['rand_code']`

Comment: ok ... i did also put .ttf file in same folder as captcha.php ... i dont need extra line with include command right ??

Comment: You do not need to include the .ttf file in captcha.php

Comment: it works ... i hit space in 1 or 2 places and it was traumatic for program ... xD thank you very much for noticing other mistakes ...

Answer (score 0):

> As you are setting header as `header("Content-type: image/png");`, page will not render other content.
>
> Just separate your `captcha` and form so that it will work.

For example your **captcha.php** will be:

```
<?php
session_start();
// build the base captcha image

$img = imagecreatetruecolor(80, 30);

$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($img, 150, 150, 150);
$red = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 0, 0);
$pink = imagecolorallocate($img, 200, 0, 150);

// build the base captcha image - END

// building randomString
function randomString($length)
{
    $chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz023456789";
    srand((double)microtime() * 1000000);
    $str = "";
    $i = 0;

    while ($i <= $length) {
        $num = rand() % 33;
        $tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1);
        $str = $str . $tmp;
        $i++;
    }
    return $str;
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= rand(1, 5); $i++) {
    $color = (rand(1, 2) == 1) ? $pink : $red;
    imageline($img, rand(5, 70), rand(5, 20), rand(5, 70) + 5, rand(5, 20) + 5, $color);
}
// building randomString - END

// fill  image with a white rectangle
imagefill($img, 0, 0, $white);

$string = randomString(rand(7, 10));
$_SESSION['string'] = $string;

imagettftext($img, 11, 0, 10, 20, $black, "Gotham-Bold.otf", $string);
// fill  image with a white rectangle - END

//  type of image
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($img);


?>
```

Comment: @Igorbeginner, Accept it if it does...Cheers!